# How do you disable an iPhone's lock screen search when guided access is enabled?

Tags: iphone, lockscreen, guided-access

I've got an iPhone Mini (iOS 17.4.1) that I use as a faux-iPod by locking it down to just [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/111795) for the Music player. However, when Guided Access is enabled, on the lock screen, you can still pull down to use search - and from there access various features of the phone.

When Guided Access is disabled, [the settings for disabling search on lock screen](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/control-access-information-lock-screen-iph9a2a69136/ios) works - you can't pull down to access the search bar.

Is there some way to disable lock screen interactions on Guided Access?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent!

How do you make the lock screen appear? It doesn't seem possible in Guided Access sessions on my iPhone SE.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your question. On the Guided App preview page for the app you use, you can draw an oval, then resize it to minimum height and full width, then drag it to the top. This prevents dragging down from the top of the screen, with the side effect that UI elements near the top of the screen may be slightly harder to tap on.

Comment: That said, when I use Guided Access I can't make the lock screen appear or use the drag from the top gesture at all.